# BASH - Creating whiptail menu from array with equal menu option and description

Tags: arrays, bash, whiptail

I would like to create a menu that takes the ls output of a folder and creates menu options and descriptions that match.

This doesn't error, but also doesn't give me a menu.

I basically want this in the menu:
array0 array0
array1 array1
array2 array2

```
#!/bin/bash

lsRes=`ls`
IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< ${lsRes}
choices=$(whiptail --title "Sizes" \
        --menu "Choose a size:" \
        25 78 12 \
        "'${array[@]}' '${array[@]}'" \
        3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
```

Also tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash


lsRes=`ls`
IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< ${lsRes}
declare -a args=( --title "Sizes" --menu "Choose a size:" 25 78 12 --)
for item in "${array[@]}"; do
    args+=("${item}" "${item}")
done
choices=$(whiptail "${args[@]}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it safely in one step. You can instead build up the arguments one at a time.

```sh
declare -a args=(
    --title "Sizes"
    --menu "Choose a size:" 25 78 12 --
)
for item in "${array[@]}"; do
    args+=("$item" "$item")
done
choices=$(whiptail "${args[@]}")
```